# How to use bind variable in plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, bind

Simple task

```
variable dept_id NUMBER

DECLARE
    max_deptno NUMBER;
    dept_name departments.department_name%TYPE := 'Education';
BEGIN
    select max(department_id)
      into max_deptno
      from departments;
    :dept_id := max_deptno + 10;
    insert into departments (department_id, department_name, location_id)
      values (:dept_id, dept_name, null);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The maximum department id is ' || max_deptno);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rows made by insert: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
END;
```

max_deptno is not NULL. Why dept_id is NULL after assignment? What am I doing wrong?

**script output:**

```
MAX(DEPARTMENT_ID)
------------------
               520 

Error starting at line 10 in command:
DECLARE
max_deptno NUMBER;
dept_name departments.department_name%TYPE := 'Education1';
BEGIN
select max(department_id)
into max_deptno
from departments;
:dept_id := max_deptno + 10;
insert into departments (department_id, department_name, location_id)
values (:dept_id, dept_name, null);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The maximum department id is ' || max_deptno);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rows made by insert: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
END;
```

Error report:

```
ORA-01400: невозможно вставить NULL в ("ANDKOM"."DEPARTMENTS"."DEPARTMENT_ID")
ORA-06512: на  line 9
01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: How do you know that `MAX_DEPTNO` is NOT NULL?  Can you show us the results of `SELECT MAX(department_id) FROM andkom.departments`?

Comment: OK.  Can you cut and paste from a single SQL*Plus session where you 1) define the host variable `DEPT_ID`, 2) `set serveroutput on`,  3) `SELECT MAX(department_id) from andkom.departments`, and then 4) run the PL/SQL block you posted? Something doesn't make sense.

Comment: OK.  Then run those statements as a script (F5) and copy and paste the script output.

Comment: @justin-cave I have updated question with this info (in the end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the same question in oracle forum and got the answer:

> Hi,
>
> This is a known issue and is dependent on a JDBC bug which has never
>   been resolved:
>   https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9456891&#9456891
>
> If your specific case does not lend itself to setting a bind variable
>   in one anonymous block and reading it in another, then the only
>   workaround (which is also considered good coding practice) is to
>   replace the SQL*Plus variable with a PL/SQL variable.
>
> Regards, Gary SQL Developer Team

Answer (score 6):

The host  variable `DEPT_ID` is not NULL after the assignment.  The problem is that your `INSERT` statement is using the local variable `NEW_DPT` in the `INSERT` and that local variable has not been assigned a value.  If you really want to use a host variable in PL/SQL (you would essentially never do this in real life) you would need to use that in your PL/SQL block

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  DECLARE
  2    max_deptno NUMBER;
  3    new_dpt NUMBER;
  4    dept_name departments.department_name%TYPE := 'Education';
  5  BEGIN
  6    select max(department_id)
  7      into max_deptno
  8      from departments;
  9    :dept_id := max_deptno + 10;
 10    insert into departments (department_id, department_name, location_id)
 11      values (:dept_id, dept_name, null);
 12    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The maximum department id is ' || max_deptno);
 13    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rows made by insert: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
 14* END;
SQL> /
The maximum department id is 270
Rows made by insert: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select :dept_id from dual;

  :DEPT_ID
----------
       280
```

More realistic, however, would be to ditch the substitution variable entirely

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  DECLARE
  2    max_deptno NUMBER;
  3    new_dpt NUMBER;
  4    dept_name departments.department_name%TYPE := 'Education';
  5  BEGIN
  6    select max(department_id)
  7      into max_deptno
  8      from departments;
  9    new_dpt := max_deptno + 10;
 10    insert into departments (department_id, department_name, location_id)
 11      values (new_dpt, dept_name, null);
 12    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The maximum department id is ' || max_deptno);
 13    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rows made by insert: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
 14* END;
SQL> /
The maximum department id is 280
Rows made by insert: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Justin, I have one minor quibble with what you said.  dept_id, in his example, is in fact a bind variable, not a substitution variable.  A substitution variable would be prefixed with a '&' not a ':', and substitution would happen in SQL*Plus, before the statement was passed to the server.

Comment: @MarkBobak - Quite right, it's not a substitution variable.  I've updated my answer to call it a host variable, though, rather than a bind variable (which it also is) just because all the local variables in the `INSERT` statement are bind variables as well in the context of what people usually mean when they talk about bind variables.

Comment: Sorry for incorrect code in my question. But I still get null in dept_id. Maybe I should turn on something:) Sorry for stupid questions. Just started to learn pl/sql

Comment: @andryuhell - Can you cut and paste from a SQL*Plus session that shows exactly what you are running and exactly what output you are getting?  I ran my examples while logged in as `HR` with the full `HR` sample schema in place.  I'm assuming that's what you're doing as well?